# Getting an object instead a number from rootState vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to get activeTables from tables state.

```
const state = {
    activeTable: 0,
    tables: [{id:1},{id:2}],
}
```

When I do rootState.tables.activeTable from another module I get Object but I would like the value.

I tried to go deeper in tree structure in console.log but I can't get the value

```
const actions = {
    async addCommand ({commit, rootState},articles) {
        console.log(rootState.tables.activeTable) // getting an object instead a number
        commit('ADD_COMMAND', {table_id:rootState.tables.activeTable,list:articles})
        await api.insert(articles)
    },
}
```

// store/index.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import products from './modules/products.js'
import tables from './modules/tables.js'
import command from './modules/command.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        products,
        tables,
        command
    },
})
```

store/modules/tables.js

```
const state = {
    activeTable: 0,
    tables: [{id:1},{id:2}],
}

const getters = {
    tables: state => state.tables,
    activeTable: state => state.activeTable,
    
}

const actions = {
    setActiveTableId (id) {
        this.commit('SET_ACTIVE_TABLE', id)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    SET_TABLES:(state, tables) => {
        state.tables = tables;
    },
    SET_ACTIVE_TABLE:(state, id) => {
        state.activeTable = id
    }
}

export default {
    state: state,
    mutations: mutations,
    getters: getters,
    actions: actions,
    strict: true,
}
```

store/modules/command.js

```
const state = {
    listCommand: []
}

const getters = {
    listCommand: state => state.listCommand
}

const actions = {
    async addCommand ({commit, rootState},articles) {
        console.log(rootState.tables)
        api.setUrl(api.url+'&table=command')
        commit('ADD_COMMAND', {table_id:rootState.tables.activeTable,list:articles})
        await api.insert(articles)
    },
    async addOrderLine({commit}, product){
        api.setUrl(api.url+'&table=orderline')
        await api.insert(product)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    ADD_COMMAND: (state, articles) => {
        state.listCommand.push(articles)
    },
    SET_LISTCOMMAND:(state, articles) => {
        state.listCommand = {table_id:state.activeTable,list:articles};
    },
}

export default {
    state: () => state,
    mutations: mutations,
    getters: getters,
    actions: actions,
    strict: true,
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but to me it looks as if you aren't correctly selecting your active table.
do rootState.tables[rootState.activeTable] if you are trying to select a table by it's index.
If you are trying to select it by id:
const selectedTable = rootState.tables.find(table => table.id === rootState.activeTable)

Comment: Yeah, I get `undefined`. How should I do to get the value of "activeTable". I can't see how get root otherwise

Comment: It doesn't work. I get `undefined`

Comment: `undefined`  for `console.log(rootState.activeTable)` and `console.log(rootState.tables)` I get the observer with tables state but I can't get the value of activeTables

Comment: It sounds like your store is set up incorrectly, also since you are writing both state and actions as const instead of properties in a store.
I think you would do best to read through the vuex docs and follow it step by step.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

Comment: I'm using ...Vuex.mapActions{['setActiveTableId']} this is the reason why I don't do this.$store.dispatch. But I still tried this and I getting that object I don't know how. I read the docs I'm lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error is in the "store/modules/tables.js"

I forgot to add {commit} argument..

```
before

const actions = {
    setActiveTableId (id) {
        this.commit('SET_ACTIVE_TABLE', id)
    }
}
after
const actions = {
    setActiveTableId ({commit},id) {
        this.commit('SET_ACTIVE_TABLE', id)
    }
}
```

Thanks all